# How to implement an UpdateView Class Based View

Tags: python, django

I'm building an app where businesses can upload their local shop with a bunch of information. Currently, there is a form which is working but I'd like to implement an UpdateView in order for businesses to update their information whenever they want.

Here is my model.py:

```
class Business(models.Model):
owner = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
logo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False, upload_to=upload_location)
players = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=PLAYERS_CHOICES, default='2-4')
average_price = models.IntegerField()
number_games = models.IntegerField()
city = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CITY_CHOICES)
address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
website = models.CharField(max_length=300)
description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Notice that I'm using a OneToOneField, since one owner can only have one business within the site.

My views.py for the form:

```
class BusinessCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
form_class = BusinessCreateForm
login_url = '/login/'
template_name = 'business/form.html'
success_url = '/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.owner = self.request.user
    return super(BusinessCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And here is my forms.py:

```
class BusinessCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Business
    fields = [
        'name',
        'logo',
        'players',
        'average_price',
        'number_games',
        'city',
        'address',
        'website',
        'description',
    ]
```

I've been checking the documentation and I haven't been able to implement an UpdateView.

How could I do it?

Thank you so much in advance!

**UPDATE**

I've tried a queryset inside my views.py and it did not work:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Business.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is preventing you from implementing an UpdateView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really explained what your difficulty implementing an `UpdateView` is. Perhaps the hint you need is to override `get_object` to return the business to update:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_objet_or_404

class BusinessUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = BusinessUpdateForm
    template_name = 'business/form.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Business, owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you Alasdair! It worked perfectly. You're right when saying that I did not explain my question correctly. In fact, I tried implement a get_query_set() to look up for the current login user and it did not work. I should have posted that. Thank you again.

Comment: Overwriting `get_queryset` and filtering by user is a possibility, but then you'll need to include the primary key or slug of the object in the URL, e.g. `/business/10/update/`. By overriding `get_object`, you don't need to include the primary key or slug in the URL anymore.

Comment: Thank you again. Do I need to include the form_valid() method within the UpdateView?

Comment: Once the business is created, it is already linked to the user, so you don't need to change it in the `form_valid` method. Make sure the `owner` field isn't included in the form.